# I keep getting 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Get' on django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a little "boards" app for practicing purposes.
I'm currently stuck on a page, where a error occurs if I try to load a paginator template.

The error traceback looks like the following:

```
AttributeError at /board/2/
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Get'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.56.101:8000/board/2/
Django Version: 1.7.6
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Get'
Exception Location: /home/web/workspace/simpleboard/board/views.py in read_board, line 38
Python Executable:  /home/web/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.4.2
Python Path:    
['/home/web/workspace/simpleboard',
 '/home/web/venv/lib/python34.zip',
 '/home/web/venv/lib/python3.4',
 '/home/web/venv/lib/python3.4/plat-linux',
 '/home/web/venv/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/home/web/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4',
 '/home/web/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/plat-linux',
 '/home/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages']


Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/home/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/web/workspace/simpleboard/board/views.py in read_board
page = request.Get.get("page") ...
▶ Local vars
```

Views:

```
def read_board(request, board_id):
    board = get_object_or_404(Board, id=board_id)
    article_list = board.article_set.order_by("-written_date")
    paginator = Paginator(article_list, 5)
    page = request.Get.get("page")           <--error here, apparently.

    try:
        articles = paginator.page(page)    
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        articles = paginator.page(1)    
    except EmptyPage:
        articles = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        "board" : board,
        "articles" : articles,
        "pages" : paginator.page_range
    }

    return render(request, "board.html", context)
```

Thanks.

PS: tab key is not working on stackoverflow, so I had to indent with spaces instead. When I press tab, it jumps to "tags" box underneath. Does anyone know what the problem is? As far as I can remember, I worked fine last time. (I'm on Mac OS by the way.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have misprinted `GET`. Use:

```
page = request.GET.get("page")
```

Please read "[Request and response objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/)" article on Django Docs.

Comment: How stupid I am. Can't believe I've been sweating 1 hour on this...Thanks.

Comment: @Bossam, you can accept this answer if it helped you